# Multidimensional Scaling Fitting in Numpy, Pandas and Sklearn (ValueError)

Tags: python, numpy, pandas, scikit-learn

I'm trying out multidimensional scaling with sklearn, pandas and numpy.  The data file Im using has 10 numerical columns and no missing values.  I am trying to take this ten dimensional data and visualize it in 2 dimensions with sklearn.manifold's multidimensional scaling as follows:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from sklearn import manifold
from sklearn.metrics import euclidean_distances

seed = np.random.RandomState(seed=3)
data = pd.read_csv('data/big-file.csv')

#  start small dont take all the data, 
#  its about 200k records
subset = data[:10000]
similarities = euclidean_distances(subset)

mds = manifold.MDS(n_components=2, max_iter=3000, eps=1e-9, 
      random_state=seed, dissimilarity="precomputed", n_jobs=1)

pos = mds.fit(similarities).embedding_
```

But I get this value error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "demo/mds-demo.py", line 18, in <module>
    pos = mds.fit(similarities).embedding_
  File "/Users/dwilliams/Desktop/Anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/manifold/mds.py", line 360, in fit
    self.fit_transform(X, init=init)
  File "/Users/dwilliams/Desktop/Anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/manifold/mds.py", line 395, in fit_transform
eps=self.eps, random_state=self.random_state)
  File "/Users/dwilliams/Desktop/Anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/manifold/mds.py", line 242, in smacof
eps=eps, random_state=random_state)
  File "/Users/dwilliams/Desktop/Anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/manifold/mds.py", line 73, in _smacof_single
raise ValueError("similarities must be symmetric")
ValueError: similarities must be symmetric
```

I thought euclidean_distances returned a symmetric matrix.  What am I doing wrong and how do I fix it?

Comment: first check that `np.allclose(similarities, similarites.T)` is `True`. when I try this with random input it works. can u try with random input?

Comment: Try using `scipy.spatial.distance_matrix`? Or if you're just using euclidean distance anyways, you can let sklearn compute them using dissimilarity="euclidean".

Comment: I ran into a similar issue and I had to patch L71 in sklearn/manifold/mds.py by multiplying the tolerance by 20
(`np.abs(similarities - similarities.T).max()`was ~1e-12 for me instead of < 1e-13, so the check was too stringent and it failed.

Comment: Would be great if down raters could provide a comment.  It's not constructive in any way to down vote and bounce without input.  Wasted time.

Comment: You need to answer Phillip Cloud's question, as well as the other questions posted in the comments. You also need to provide test data to replicate the problem.

Comment: Can you give data to reproduce it? Preferably using `random()`.

Answer (score 13):

I ran across the same problem; it turned out that my data was an array of `np.float32` and the reduced float precision caused the distance matrix to be asymmetric.  I fixed the issue by converting my data to `np.float64` before running MDS on it.

Here's an example that uses random data to illustrate the issue:

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.manifold import MDS
from sklearn.metrics import euclidean_distances
from sklearn.datasets import make_classification

data, labels = make_classification()
mds = MDS(n_components=2)

similarities = euclidean_distances(data.astype(np.float64))
print np.abs(similarities - similarities.T).max()
# Prints 1.7763568394e-15
mds.fit(data.astype(np.float64))
# Succeeds

similarities = euclidean_distances(data.astype(np.float32))
print np.abs(similarities - similarities.T).max()
# Prints 9.53674e-07
mds.fit(data.astype(np.float32))
# Fails with "ValueError: similarities must be symmetric"
```

Comment: Thx，It really works.  but after changed to float64,
 I got another warning:
/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/sklearn/manifold/mds.py:396: UserWarning: The MDS API has changed. ``fit`` now constructs an dissimilarity matrix from data. To use a custom dissimilarity matrix, set ``dissimilarity='precomputed'``.

Answer (score 6):

Had the same problem a while ago. Another solution, which I believe much more efficient, is to compute the distance only for the upper triangular matrix, and later copy to the lower part.

It can be done with scipy as follows:

```
from scipy.spatial.distance import squareform,pdist                                                              
similarities = squareform(pdist(data,'speuclidean'))
```